# spring batch: how to set a double field as null in database if the field in the file is empty?

Tags: java, spring

I have the following csv file

```
6/1/13,"139,237",37,
6/2/13,"149,582",55,234.71
6/3/13,"457,425",132,211.48
6/4/13,"466,870",141,
6/5/13,"472,385",194,281.35
```

The last field some time is empty and we need to load them into database as null is it is empty. The column name is earning. So I am tring to use the following in class of com.mkyong.Report

```
public double getEarning() {
        return Earning;
    }
     public void setEarning(String earning) {
            if (earning.isEmpty()) {
                Earning=(Double)null;
            } else {
            Earning = Double.parseDouble(earning);
            }
        }
```

the configuration is:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" 
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

    <bean id="report" class="com.mkyong.Report" scope="prototype" />

    <batch:job id="reportJob">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="cvsFileItemReader" writer="mysqlItemWriter"
                             commit-interval="2">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <!--need to specify scope="step" for cvsFileItemReader, othewise it will throw the error of JobParameters -->
    <!--Cannot Be Found On Object Of Type BeanExpressionContext-->
    <bean id="cvsFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader" scope="step">

        <property name="resource" value="#{jobParameters['input.file']}" />
        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <!-- split it -->
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                        <property name="names" value="date,impressions,clicks,earning" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="fieldSetMapper">   
                    <!-- return back to reader, rather than a mapped object. -->
                    <!--
                   <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.PassThroughFieldSetMapper" />
                    --> 
                    <!-- map to an object -->
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                        <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="report" />
                    </bean>         
                </property>

            </bean>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="mysqlItemWriter"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sql">
            <value>
            <![CDATA[        
                insert into RAW_REPORT(DATE,IMPRESSIONS,CLICKS,EARNING) 
            values (:date, :impressions, :clicks, :earning)
            ]]>
            </value>
        </property>
        <!-- It will take care matching between object property and sql name parameter -->
        <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider" />
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

But it complains the following:

```
     Caused by: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'target' on field 'earning': rejected value []; codes [typeMismatch.target.earning,typeMismatch.earning,typeMismatch.double,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [target.earning,earning]; arguments []; default message [earning]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'float' for property 'earning'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.mapFieldSet(BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.java:189)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper.mapLine(DefaultLineMapper.java:43)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:180)
```

Comment: You have a null pointer exception in Report.java, line 35 in com.mkyong.Report.getEarning(Report.java:35). Can you attach getEarning() function?

Comment: the get method is simple:public double getEarning() {
        return Earning;
    }

Comment: @punseti, sorry I copied the wrong error and I have corrected it, it should "java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String"

Comment: @punseti: you are correct, after I use Double (object type) instead of double, it runs well. Thanks for your hint. You could write a answer and then I could mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Use class Double instead of double

```
public Double getEarning() {
    return Earning;
}
```

If earning column must be null you can not use primitive type and have to use Object to set null when are collected from database.